# Get all options in a select menu

Tags: jquery-selectors

How do I get all the options (text,not the value) of a select menu by by specifying its id

Answer (score 1):

```
var textArr = $("#mySelect").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
alert(textArr);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd3PS/). And see http://api.jquery.com/map/